# Symfony3 Factory as Service

Tags: symfony, service, factory-pattern

I have been trying to get my head around this

http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/factories.html

But there seems to be a piece missing that tires it all together *OR* I am completely missing the point.

The example has a factory Class

```
class NewsletterManagerFactory
{
    public static function createNewsletterManager()
    {
        $newsletterManager = new NewsletterManager();

        // ...

        return $newsletterManager;
    }
}
```

And then that factory is configured via a service to be the factory class and method for `NewsletterManager` service.

```
services:
    app.newsletter_manager_factory:
        class: AppBundle\Email\NewsletterManagerFactory

    app.newsletter_manager:
        class:   AppBundle\Email\NewsletterManager
        factory: 'app.newsletter_manager_factory:createNewsletterManager'
```

So now we have a `NewsletterManager` Class that is aware of the `NewsletterManagerFactory` Class via the `factory:` param in `services.yml`

**Question**

How do you make use of this configuration? What is now exposed inside of `NewsletterManager` that allows me to call `createNewsletterManager` in the factory Class?

The two services are still completely separate as far as I can tell?

Answer (score 12):

I used this pattern once. Here is the use case for it.

Imagine that you have multiple widget classes i.e. `Acme\Widget1`, `Acme\Widget2`, `Acme\WidgetN`.

Each widget has an advanced instantiation process so you decide to use a factory. It also has a complex dependency chain that is needed for each widget to be instantiated. I.e. `Acme\Dependency1`, `Acme\Dependency2`, `Acme\Dependency3`.

So what you'd do is to create `Acme\WidgetFactory` service with dependencies once. Then you need to specify that `Acme\WidgetFactory` as factory for each widget. In case something changes in the way of widget instantiation you only need to change one class and one service definition. All 1 to N widget services stay the same.

Here is the example...

Typical way of implementation:

```
acme.widget1:
    class: Acme\Widget1
    factory: ['Acme\Widget1', 'create']
    arguments: ['@acme.dependency1', '@acme.dependency2', '@acme.dependencyN'] 

acme.widget2:
    class: Acme\Widget2
    factory: ['Acme\Widget2', 'create']
    arguments: ['@acme.dependency1', '@acme.dependency2', '@acme.dependencyN'] 

acme.widgetN:
    class: Acme\WidgetN
    factory: ['Acme\WidgetN', 'create']
    arguments: ['@acme.dependency1', '@acme.dependency2', '@acme.dependencyN']
```

Here you have a strong smell of code duplication. If you want to change something you need to do it N times.

Instead here is what you can do.

```
acme.widget_factory:
    class: Acme\WidgetFactory
    arguments: ['@acme.dependency1', '@acme.dependency2', '@acme.dependencyN']

acme.widget1:
    class: Acme\Widget1
    factory: ['@acme.widget_factory', createWidget]

acme.widget2:
    class: Acme\Widget2
    factory: ['@acme.widget_factory', createWidget]

acme.widgetN:
    class: Acme\WidgetN
    factory: ['@acme.widget_factory', createWidget]
```

Code duplication is gone.

Appeared small inconvenience... Factory does not know what concrete class to instantiate. I used the following technique for it.

I tagged each widget and then during compiler pass added extra parameter to factory.

```
acme.widget_factory:
    class: Acme\WidgetFactory
    arguments: ['@acme.dependency1', '@acme.dependency2', '@acme.dependencyN']

acme.widget1:
    class: Acme\Widget1
    factory: ['@acme.widget_factory', createWidget]
    tags:
        - { name: acme.widget }

acme.widget2:
    class: Acme\Widget2
    factory: ['@acme.widget_factory', createWidget]
    tags:
        - { name: acme.widget }

acme.widgetN:
    class: Acme\WidgetN
    factory: ['@acme.widget_factory', createWidget]
    tags:
        - { name: acme.widget }
```

Then in DepencencyInjection\AcmeDemoExtension.php

```
class AcmeDemoExtension implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $widgets = $container->findTaggedServiceIds('acme.widget');
        foreach ($widgets as $id => $tags) {
            $definition = $container->getDefinition($id);
            $definition->setArguments([$definition->getClass()]);
        }
    }
}
```

and finally in the factory...

```
class AcmeWidgetFactory
{
    //.....
    public static function createWidget($class) 
    {
        //.....
        return new $class(/*  dependencies */);
        //.....
    }
    //.....
}
```

So at the end when you do `$this->get('acme.widget1')` the factory method with class name as a parameter is called. Factory already has all dependencies and knows the logic of class instantiation. So it does all the work and return required widget instance.

Comment: Thanks this is useful and I can see why this is handy. But I am still not clear on why you add the `factory` param to the service. For instance the `acme.widget2` service now has a factory param of `['@acme.widget_factory', createWidget]` but how is that used inside of the class `Acme\Widget2`. Can you show me what the `Acme\Widget2` class might look like?

Comment: Nothing special in there. Just a class with a constructor. All instantiation logic is moved to a factory. When Symfony wants to instantiate `acme.widget2` it takes instance of `acme.widget_factory` and calls its method `createWidget()` with widget class name as parameter. All complex logic of instantiating and setting up happens there. At the end `createWidget()` returns ready to be used instance of `Acme\Widget2`.

Comment: Hi! So useful example, but I can't guess how to pass and get dependency arguments from the controller (doing that ->get('service.id')) to the factory. Thank you in advance. Cheers!

Comment: Hi, could you please elaborate on how the WidgetFactory's "createWidget()" method gets the dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

This is simple. If you gonna call

```
$nm = $container->get('app.newsletter_manager')
```

then the newsletter manager will be created by factory automatically.

Comment: Ok so the point is that the service returns a new object. Rather than the service itself?

Comment: Exactly. The service (the factory) returns an new service or entity or what ever your factory creates.

Comment: @JakeN, no, the return value of the factory method is the service. The factory class itself is just an intermediary that is not directly adressable. You can however write a separate service definition for the factory too, if desireable.